# Get the value of textbox in jaavscript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" ><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
  <button type="button" id="butt">click here </button>
</form>
<script>
  const lname=document.getElementById('lname').value;
  const fname=document.getElementById('fname').value;
  document.getElementById('butt').onclick= function() {submit();}
  function submit(lname,fname){
      alert(lname);
      console.log(fname);
  }
</script>
```

I know this is kiddish. I've been trying to get the value inside a html input box and alert it using js. Its returning as `undefined` error. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your submit function is looking for arguments called `lname` and `fname`, which you have not passed, instead of the variables you've already declared. Try removing the parameters from your submit function definition.

Comment: @mykaf this still won't read the current values of the inputs when the function runs.

Comment: Further, move the variable declarations themselves into the function - that way, they will grab the values of the inputs at function runtime instead of when the script is first instantiated (at which time they will be blank).

Comment: Hi, i tried like you said. Now, its just giving out an empty response without anything. Like, just blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is returning undefined is because you have arguments which are never used.

Answer Below:

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
  <button type="button" id="butt">click here </button>
</form>
<script>
  var lname = document.getElementById('lname');
  var fname = document.getElementById('fname');
  var btn = document.getElementById('butt');

  btn.onclick = function() {
    submit();
  }

  function submit() {
    alert(lname.value);
    console.log(fname.value);
  }
</script>
```

You're Welcome!

Comment: Also if you need to use the variables elsewhere, change the declaration to var instead of const, or if you don't, move the variables into the function "submit()".

Answer (score 1):

The two issues I'm seeing are:

1. The `submit` function is expecting two arguments which aren't being supplied when calling it.
2. You're reading the values of the inputs immediately when the page loads, before the user has had a chance to type anything.

Remove the function arguments entirely and read the values in the function, after the user has clicked the button.  For example:

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" ><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
  <button type="button" id="butt">click here </button>
</form>
<script>
  document.getElementById('butt').onclick= function() {submit();}
  function submit(){
      // define and read the values here
      const lname=document.getElementById('lname').value;
      const fname=document.getElementById('fname').value;

      alert(lname);
      console.log(fname);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much for helping out this simpleton!!